# Las notificaciones de FCM solo quedan en la barra superior (Flutter)

Tags: android, firebase, fcm, flutter

Buenas tardes a todos,

Actualmente tengo una app hecha con Flutter pero las notificaciones caen en la barra superior y no sobre salen como lo hacian en un principio (las estoy mandando desde la consola de Firebase Cloud Messaging).

Quiero que salga el PopUp así sin tener que bajar la barra superior.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como comenté en un principio me pasa tanto cuando mando un mensaje simple desde la consola de firebase (solo pongo titulo y cuerpo del mensaje) y si lo mando desde una función en Firebase Cloud Functions.

AndroidManifest: (En una parte tengo esto cargado)

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Configuración en la parte del Main.dart

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on message $message');

      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on resume $message');

      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on launch $message');

      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions( const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true,badge: true,alert: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings setting){
      print('Setting registered: $setting');
    });
```

Comment: Puedes poner una imagen de como aparece actualmente? también la data que le envías

Comment: @diegoveloper acabo de agregar todo , los mensajes los mando desde la consola directamente solo con un título y cuerpo para el mensaje (siempre tengo marcada la prioridad alta pero como que no hace efecto porque entiendo que no se muestra de forma flotante porque no detecta la prioridad alta del mensaje o algo así)

Comment: Cuando entras a Settings -> Apps , notifications ->  y buscas tu app, que tipo de configuración tiene? estás suscrito a un topic?  puedes poner un pantalla de esa configuración

Comment: Estaba leyendo un poco sobre ese FCM plugin, solo veo que las notificaciones llegan al system tray por default, por eso no se muestra la notificación como popup, para eso puedes usar otro plugin que es el de Local notifications, para que una vez que recibas el mensaje, puedes mostrar el popup: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: En la configuración están habilitadas las notificaciones junto con los puntos de notificación. Por otro lado entiendo que se puede hacer con el plugin que mencionas pero no funciona cuando la app esta completamente cerrada , si la app está abierta no necesito notificaciones porque en la app tengo un icono que muestra que tenes un mensaje.

Comment: Vi que si las mandas por Firebase Cloud Functions podes setear la prioridad del mensaje pero igualmente no funciona , otros agregan clases.java para luego agregarlas al manifest (eso supuestamente les permite controlar todo pero al mandar la app a mi celu no funciona tampoco :S ). Entiendo que es complejo porque cada persona dice cosas diferentes pero parece ser que por ahora va a tener que quedar de esa forma u.u Gracias Diego por tu tiempo !! @diegoveloper

Comment: @Gonza usa setPriority()  o setImportance() dependiendo del OS.

Comment: Dale , graciass!! @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba leyendo un poco sobre ese FCM plugin, solo veo que las notificaciones llegan al system tray por default, por eso no se muestra la notificación como popup, para eso puedes usar otro plugin que es el de Local notifications, para que una vez que recibas el mensaje, puedes mostrar el popup:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Tu código quedaría algo así :

```
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
            print('on message $message');

                //...

                _showBigTextNotification();


          },


   ....

        Future _showBigTextNotification() async {
        var bigTextStyleInformation = new BigTextStyleInformation(
            'Lorem <i>ipsum dolor sit</i> amet, consectetur <b>adipiscing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
            htmlFormatBigText: true,
            contentTitle: 'overridden <b>big</b> content title',
            htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
            summaryText: 'summary <i>text</i>',
            htmlFormatSummaryText: true);
        var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'big text channel id',
            'big text channel name',
            'big text channel description',
            style: AndroidNotificationStyle.BigText,
            styleInformation: bigTextStyleInformation);
        var platformChannelSpecifics =
            new NotificationDetails(androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, null);
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            0, 'big text title', 'silent body', platformChannelSpecifics);
      }
```

No te olvides importar el plugin e inicializarlo, puedes guiarte de este sample code:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-example-tab-

NOTA:

Puedes validar si estás o no en background , usa el flag  `mounted`, si está en false lanzas la notificación local.

Comment: @diegodeveloper puede ser que solo funcione con la app abierta? solo en ese caso funciona bien , pero necesito que funcione en cualquier situación.   Es como que solo se activa el OnMessage , pero no en OnResume o OnLaunch

Comment: cuando estás con la app en background, a que método entra cuando llega el push ?

Comment: Cuando está de fondo no veo que entre a ningún método  , solo cuando está abierta muestra que entra al OnMessage.

Comment: revisando este cuadro : https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages  ,  si tu app está en background debería entrar a onMessage , pero si tu app está cerrada, el plugin no soporta, porque lo que hace el plugin es comunicar el host (android/ios) con dart, pero si la app está cerrada, no hay forma de que dart pueda recibir los datos, lo que podrías hacer es hacer un fork de plugin y agregarla lo necesario, las notificaciones locales dentro de código nativo.

Comment: ahh entonces no me sirve el plugin :S , para tener el mensaje tipo "heads up" tuve que entrar a las opciones de mi app , notificaciones , selecionar el canal por default y cambiar la prioridad para que suene y muestre en vez de solo hacer sonar y dejar la notificacion en la barra superior. De momento no existe una función para mandar al usuario a esas opciones para así poder subir la prioridad? Entiendo que en android tipo nativo se puede con un intent pero no estoy seguro de si se puede hacer lo mismo en flutter. por ahora encontré esto https://flutter.io/platform-channels/ y un plugin .

Comment: Como estás usando el plugin FCM, está limitado a lo que trae el plugin, y al recibir el mensaje lo unico que hace es comunicarlo con Dart, pero si la app está cerrada, el plugin no puede hacer nada, lo que podrías hacer es escribir código nativo , en java/kotlin   y  swift/object-c , para que muestre la notificación directamente, eso es con platform-channels, lo que te recomiendo es que uses el código del plugin FCM para que te guiés .

Comment: El código es libre:  https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85200/discussion-between-gonza-g-and-diegoveloper).

Comment: @diegodeveloper al final pude solucionarlo, quité el plugin de local notifications y dejé el de firebase_messaging . Por defecto este último que es el normal podia recibir las notificaciones pero sin la prioridad alta por lo que solo sonaba pero no mostraba el tipico "heads Up" . Entonces empecé a modificar la clase MainActivity para que detecte la version del sistema y cree un canal de notificaciones con la prioridad alta (con un ID especifico obviamente). Entonces agregue la linea "android_channel_id" en el playload que mando junto con el detalle del ID. Esto hizo que muestre todo!!

Comment: genial, entonces modificaste el MainActivity de tu proyecto flutter, creaste un canal de notificaciones con un nombre de terminado y prioridad alta, y en el payload usas ese canal.

Comment: exactamente!! ahora deberia ver si las notificaciones se pierden con una versión de android menor o si caen en el canal por defecto . Ya que las que mando por la funcion apuntan a un canal que no va a existir.

Comment: lo que me parece raro es que tengas que hacerlo desde código nativo,  probaste desde Dart llamar a subscribeToTopic? https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: La función suscribeToTopic funciona correctamente , no entiendo que relación tiene con que se muestren las notificaciones tipo "heads up" , las mismas siempre funcionaron pero solo queria ese tipo de notificación "heads up" .

Comment: claro, pero lo raro es que tengas que modificar el MainActivity, lo cual eso no indica las instrucciones del plugin , solo hay interacción con Dart y archivos de configuración

Comment: claro pero el plugin de firebase_messaging funciona correctamente con los pasos mencionados en la documentación solo que no los muestra sobresaliendo la pantalla , sino que si o si se debe bajar la barra para leer todo. La solución que implemente es super provisoria porque estimo puede haber novedades en el evento de Flutter en diciembre o por lo menos eso espero. Por ahora se puede hacer lo que me mencioné para verlas de esa forma tipo "Heads Up Notifications" . Gracias por toda la ayuda diego !!

Comment: No hay de que, quizas puedas registrar un issue en el repo de Flutter e indicar el workaround que hiciste para que funcione : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba exactamente y por si a alguien le sirve, lo que me funciono es entrar a la información de la app en tu dispositivo o emulador y activar permisos de mostrar notificaciones en segundo plano, en el canal de notificaciones flotantes hacer lo mismo, prácticamente habilitarle todo.

Comment: Hola @Kevin. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, también puede consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)»

Comment: A mi me parece que sí trata de responder a la pregunta. No digo que sea una respuesta ejemplar, pero está compartiendo una experiencia que tuvo en la que tenía ese mismo problema (a su vista) y comparte lo que le funcionó ¿Por qué no es una respuesta válida?

Comment: me pregunto lo mismo, bueno revisare los enlaces, yo solo trate de responder lo que me funciono a mi